Правильные имена для линковщика gcc (ld)
Я начинающий программист.
Часто компилирую другие исходные коды без make-файлов.
Очень часто компилятор отказывается компилировать исходный код, потому что не заданы
значения в переменной LIBS в make-файле.
Как узнать правильные название подключаемых библиотек?
Например если используешь функции из libz.a указываешь параметр LIBS = -lz.

Отрезаешь от имени файла библиотеки lib спереди и .a сзади, приписываешь -l спереди и помещаешь в конец командной строки.

Спасибо. А как узнать какой заголовочный файл (.h) связан с какой библиотекой (.a)?

Ход мысли другой: ищите нужную функциональность. Отыскиваете её в каком-то пакете, пакет содержит .a и заголовки. Например: https://refspecs.linuxbase.org/LSB_3.0.0/LSB-Core-generic/LSB-Core-generic/generic-lsb.html.
